# Best way to send data to server through ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax

From searching the web, I found this two method to send data into the server by jQuery `.ajax()` the first method is working fine for me but I need to keep the code cleaner (since I have more items to send to server than this example).

How can I use this second way of wrapping data? and which one is better?

1-

```
var uid = $('.userid').val();
var em = $('.emailadd').val();
var data='userid='+uid+'&emailadd='+em;
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "assets/.../exe.php",
    data: data,

});
```

2-

```
var uid = $('.userid').val();
var em = $('.emailadd').val();
var data={userid: "uid", emailadd: "em"};
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "assets/.../exe.php",
    data: data,

});
```

Comment: simplest is to use `serialize()` on a whole form and skip manually creating data strings or objects yourself

Comment: Have you read the docs on [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is idiomatic:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "assets/.../exe.php",
    data: {
        userid: $('.userid').val (),
        em: $('.emailadd').val ()
    },
});
```

As was mentioned, perhaps you should [read the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) before asking questions.

Answer (score -2):

Although the first is clean, my advise would be to create a JSON line, and sending it through the data. You will need to create the JSON string, and then parse it, as such:

```
var text = '{ "employees" : [' + '{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' + '{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' + '{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ]}';
```

And then:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

What you will do is assign that obj into the data and encode it, so:

```
var data=json_encode(obj);
```

And on the receiving side you will have to "json_decode" it to be able to access it by writing:

```
obj.employees[1].firstName;
```

Read more about JSON here:
http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp

Comment: So you're building a up a JSON string... then converting that to an object... then converting it back to a string again? Why not just pass an object to JQuery's `$.ajax()` function?

Comment: building json manually is a terrible practice and far more prone to error than using serialization methods. This is a completely mickey mouse solution. Also you are mixing javascript and php methods that are not compatible